# Postfix - Exclude user from sending and receiving to-from some domains

Tags: postfix, dovecot

In postfix or dovecot, it's possible exclude an user from sending and receiving mail to and from some domains by creating a rule that the user cannot deactivate?

Comment: dovecot is an IMAP server, so fully unrelated to the aspect of *sending* emails.

Comment: [SOLVED] I post the solution in case someone needs it in the future: For incoming mail i've applied sieve rules: [LINK](https://blog.zimbra.com/2021/07/zimbra-skillz-using-sieve-filters-on-zimbra/) For outgoing, a combination of senders_access and recipient_access: [LINK](https://wiki.zimbra.com/wiki/Restrict_users_to_certain_domain)